Roslyn InsertNodesBefore and ReplaceNode 'Unable to cast object of type X' Exception
I'm trying to create a method which can insert some code into a specific position like this:
public static class CodeModifier
{
public delegate SyntaxNode InsertionPosition(SyntaxNode root);

        public static string InsertCodeBlock(this string originalCode, string codeBlockToInsert, InsertionPosition insertionPosition)
        {
            SyntaxTree syntaxTree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(originalCode);
            CompilationUnitSyntax root = syntaxTree.GetCompilationUnitRoot();
    
            var cbNode = SyntaxFactory.ParseSyntaxTree(codeBlockToInsert).GetRoot() as CompilationUnitSyntax;
    
            var newCodeBlock = SyntaxFactory.ParseStatement(codeBlockToInsert);
    
    
            SyntaxNode insertionPoint = insertionPosition(root);
            
    
            if (insertionPoint != null)
            {
                var _asd = (CompilationUnitSyntax)insertionPoint;
    
                root = root.InsertNodesBefore(insertionPoint, [cbNode]);
            }
            else
            {
                //root = root.AddMembers((MemberDeclarationSyntax)newCodeBlock);
            }
    
            return root.ToFullString();
        }
    
        public static InsertionPosition InsertAtLine(int line)
        {
            return (root) => FindNodeByLine(root, line);
        }
    
        public static InsertionPosition InsertAfterLine(string lineContent)
        {
            return (root) => FindNodeByContent(root, lineContent)?.Parent;
        }
    
        public static InsertionPosition InsertBeforeLine(string lineContent)
        {
            return (root) => FindNodeByContent(root, lineContent);
        }
    
        private static SyntaxNode FindNodeByLine(SyntaxNode root, int line)
        {
            return root.DescendantNodes()
                       .FirstOrDefault(node =>
                           node.GetLocation().GetMappedLineSpan().StartLinePosition.Line + 1 == line);
        }
    
        private static SyntaxNode FindNodeByContent(SyntaxNode root, string content)
        {
            return root.DescendantNodes()
                       .OfType<StatementSyntax>()
                       .FirstOrDefault(node => node.ToFullString().Contains(content));
        }
    }

But getting next error

'Unable to cast object of type
'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax.UsingDirectiveSyntax' to type
'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax.CompilationUnitSyntax'.'

on InsertionPoint (as I assume) cast.
It seems that it won't cast specific Syntax to CompilationUnitSyntax. Whenever position I choose.
I tried to use root like this:
root = SyntaxFactory.ParseSyntaxTree(codeBlockToInsert).GetRoot()

there were no errors but also no modifications was made in result.
The ReplaceNode() returns the same exception.
